# Help with a form using $_POST and $PHP_SELF

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I will try to describe what I want to do as best as possible. I want to create a webpage using HTML and PHP. The webpage will use several forms to receive inputs from a user to be stored for later use. I only want a form to appear to the user after the previous form has been submitted. For instance, I have 3 forms:

1. What is your first name? ***_*** [SUBMIT]
2. What is your middle name? ***_*** [SUBMIT]
3. What is your last name? ***_*** [SUBMIT]

I only want the 2nd question to show up after the 1st submit is set. And I only want the 3rd question to show up after both the 1st and 2nd submits are set.

I want the webpage to look like this as the user enters and submits his information:

How the webpage looks at first:

---

1. What is your first name? *Billy* [SUBMIT]

---

How the webpage looks after user presses 1st submit:

---

1. What is your first name? *Billy* [SUBMIT]
2. What is your middle name? *Joe* [SUBMIT]

---

How the webpage looks after user presses second submit:

---

1. What is your first name? *Billy* [SUBMIT]
2. What is your middle name? *Joe* [SUBMIT]
3. What is your last name? *Smith* [SUBMIT]

---

I was hoping to use accomplish this using $PHP_SELF in the action fields of my forms and by also using the $_POST method. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Edit: Clarity

Comment: Is this just simplified/playing around code? Because this sort of thing in production public websites makes me want to bury a battleaxe in the site's designer's vacuum-filled skull...

Comment: This looks like for a jQuery job !

Comment: As you can see, I did not post any actual code. I was just trying to show what I want my webpage to look like. I am sorry that you want to use a battleaxe for such violent things.

Comment: I don't have any idea what is trying to be accomplished. Could you please provide more context?

Comment: @user845454 I think Marc B is trying to say that you should just use one form for all three names.  Making your user submit three different forms just to gather the name is likely to cause some "user rage" and/or brain aneurysms.

Comment: @Charles Sprayberry Thanks for the clarification. The example that I posted is extremely dumbed down for the sake of simplifying the question. I am actually taking DNA data inputs at a research facility. So, don't worry, I am not using this for stupidly mundane applications that would cause "user rage."

Answer (score 0):

This Should be it

```
 <?php
     session_start();
     if($_POST['btnOne'])
       $_SESSION['ShowSecond'] = true;
     if($_POST['btnTwo'])
       $_SESSION['ShowThird'] = true;
    ?>
    <form name="formOne">
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="bntOne" value="One">
    </form>
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['ShowSecond'])) { ?>
    <form name="formTwo">
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="bntTwo" value="Two">
    </form>
    <?php }
    if(isset($_SESSION['ShowThird']))
    {
    ?>
    <form name="formThree">
    ...
    <input type="submit" name="btnThree" value="Three">
    </form>
    <?php } ?>
    ?>
```

just make that session_start() is executed as first line in your php files

Comment: Thank you Senad. This was extremely helpful. However, do you know a good way to store the user inputs for further use in the webpage? I am trying to use the POST method but every time I hit submit, it seems that the POST variables are lost. Any suggestions?

Comment: Accept answer if this is what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session as suggested by Senad Meškin or create hidden input fields in forms to pass data across multiple submissions. Play around with this code and figure out how it goes.

```
        <form name="myform" method="post" action="">
  <?php if(!isset($_POST['firstname']))
         {?>
            First Name?
           <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
  <?php  }
        elseif(!isset($_POST['middlename']))
         {?>
      <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstname'] ?>">
            First Name? <?php echo $_POST['firstname'] ?><br>
            Middle Name?
            <input type="text" name="middlename" value="">

  <?php  }
        elseif(!isset($_POST['lastname']))
         {?>
      <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstname'] ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="middlename" value="<?php echo $_POST['middlename'] ?>">
          First Name? <?php echo $_POST['firstname'] ?><br>
          Middle Name? <?php echo $_POST['middlename'] ?><br>
          Last Name?
         <input type="text" name="lastname" value="">
  <?php  }else{ ?>
      <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstname'] ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="middlename" value="<?php echo $_POST['middlename'] ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $_POST['lastname'] ?>">
          First Name? <?php echo $_POST['firstname'] ?><br>
          Middle Name? <?php echo $_POST['middlename'] ?><br>
          Last Name? <?php echo $_POST['lastname'] ?><br>

  <?php  } ?>

         <input type="submit" name="submitbtn" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

Ofcourse this code may be organised better into functions as you can see there is a repeating pattern.